# skrollr stopAnimateTo sets scrollTop back to 0

Tags: animated, skrollr

I've got an skrollr page with autoplay (animateTo) and an Stop function, fired by an button.

Problem, after fireing the stop function the page is stopped  and "scrolled" back to top.

regards

martin

Comment: Show code, can't reproduce.

Comment: function autoplay(dauer, lupopos) {
 //ANIMATION BIS ENDE
 skrollr.get().animateTo(lupopos, { duration: dauer},       {interruptible: true});
  
    }
     function stop() {
     skrollr.get().stopAnimateTo();
    }

Comment: http://jsbin.com/golizuhu/1/edit

Comment: Thanks! I don't really know why It works, but it does ;)

I fire the stop function with an link, I changed it from
onClick="stop();" to onclick="setTimeout(stop, 150);"

Comment: Links are not meant for that. Use a `<button>` element and style it the way you want.